# Google Spread Sheet extrapolation

Tags: date, google-sheets, extrapolation

How to generate dates that correspond to the sequence Monday, Wednesday, Friday, which is repeating every week?

For example, if Monday is 25/7/2016, I would like to have the following sequence in one column:

25/7/2016

27/7/2016

29/7/2016

1/8/2016

3/8/2016 and so on.

Since the "select-and-drag" extrapolation does not work, I do not know, how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dates are in cell A1:A3, In cells A4:A6 enter =A1+7 in A4, enter =A2+7 in A5, and enter =A3+7 in A6.
Then select cells A4:A6. Grab the + in the right corner of A6 and drag down. I had to format the dates mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: It works, thanks. ps: I haven't seen any reason, why one would need three formulas and indeed, it suffices to enter the formula only in `A4`.